# Как обойти замыкание в jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Добрый день.

Столкнулась впервые с понятием замыкания в jQuery и не могу его обойти.

Замыкание происходит в функции reward:

```
     $(document).ready(function ()
      {
          var messages = [
                    "Nice Job!",
                    "Excellent clickin'!",
                    "That was Awesome!",
                    "Man are you good!",
                    "Boom!",
                    "You're a pro!",
                    "Unbelievable!",
                    "Insanity!",
                    "You're on fire!",
                    "That was crazy!",
                    "You are blowin' my mind!"
    ]

    var levels = 0;

    reward = function()
    {   
        $('.ball-container').css('display','none');

        $('.message_container').css('position', 'relative');

        for(levels = 0; levels <= messages.length; levels++){

        $('#text').css('visibility','visible').html(messages[levels]);

        $('#next_level').css('visibility','visible').html('Next Level: ' + levels);
        }

    window.setTimeout(hideText, 2000)
   };

    hideText = function()
    {
        $('.message_container').css('position', 'absolute');
        $('#text').css('visibility','hidden');
        $('#next_level').css('visibility','hidden');
        $('.ball-container').css('display','block');
        $('.ball').click(reward);
    };

    $('.ball').click(reward);

   });
```

Функция `reward` вызывается при клике на определенную фигуру на странице. Все решения, найденные в сети, не сработали.

Спасибо.

**Обновление**

Проблема в том, что при данном коде levels всегда равняется 11 (т.е. максимальной величине messages.length). А должна быть итерация со значением от 0 до 11. Причина такого поведения кода в замыкании JS/Jquery. Я пробовала переписать код, чтоб была нужная мне итерация, однако не меняется.

**Обновление**

[[@Zelta](/users/11139/zelta)](/users/11139/zelta), спасибо за разъяснения. В общем, сработало таким образом

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
 var messages = [
        "Nice Job!",
        "Excellent clickin'!",
        "That was Awesome!"
                ]

var levels = 0;
$('.ball').click(function(){

if(levels <11){

flashMessage();

flashMessage = function()
{
var message = messages[levels];

$('#text').text(message);

levels+=1;  
$('#level').text(levels+1);
};
```

Так и не поняла, почему в for цикл срабатывает сразу, а не пошагово.

Comment: @number1985, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, что значит "не могу его обойти" ?

Comment: Проблема в том, что при данном коде levels всегда равняется 11 (т.е. максимальной величине messages.length). А должна быть итерация со значением от 0 до 11. Причина такого поведения кода в замыкании JS/Jquery. Я пробовала переписать код, чтоб была нужная мне итерация, однако не меняется.

Comment: @number1985 у вас переменная levels существует как глобальная, поэтому где-то в другой функции она переопределяется. Добавьте перед var перед переменной.

Comment: Во-первых, не путайте js и jquery. Во-вторых, вы точно уверены, что замыкание — это то, о чем вы думаете? В-третьих, как вы определили, что levels всегда равняется 11?  Поставьте туда отладочный принт. Если оно и правда всегда равняется 11, это очень странно. Приведите, пожалуйста, больше кода?

Comment: Приведите содержание `messages`

Comment: Добавила в вопрос весь код. Не работает ни при глобальной, ни при локальной levels. 
В том, что вопрос в замыкании, уверенна почти на 100%, потому что такая проблема не у меня одной возникала. Но решить на основании ответов в сети не получается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Еще раз повторю.

Во-первых, замыкание — это, грубо говоря, функция в функции. Я никак не могу понять, причем оно тут.

Во-вторых, давайте внимательно посмотрим на ваш цикл. На каждом шаге цикла вы в контейнер `#text` кладете `messages[levels]`, в контейнер `#next_level` — `'Next Level: ' + levels`. Естественно, когда цикл отработает полностью, в `#text` окажется `messages[11]`, а в `#next_level` — `11` (да, кстати, в массиве `messages` всего 11 элементов, а поскольку нумерация начинается с нуля, правильно поставить строгое условие на окончание цикла).

Теперь поместим строку `console.log(levels);` в тело цикла. При нажатии `.ball` в консоли можно наблюдать такую картину:

[image: ForLoop console output]

Очевидно, цикл отработал полностью ([убедитесь сами](http://jsfiddle.net/2z5rhvLL/)).

Теперь, внимание, вопрос: а что вы хотите добиться, 11 раз перезаписывая значение `#text` и `#next_level`? Мне лично кажется, что здесь что-то не так, и «замыкания» тут уж явно ни при чем.

Comment: Статья про замыкания, чтобы исключить путаницу: http://habrahabr.ru/post/38642/

Comment: Должны появляться сообщения из цикла по очереди после нажатия на фигуру. Как здесь http://jenniferdewalt.com/bouncing_ball.html. Т.е. у меня цикл срабатывает и постоянно выдает 11. А должно быть 1, 2, 3 и т.п. Ну и данные из цикла по очереди. 
В статье http://habrahabr.ru/post/38642/ есть похожий пример 
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
   links[i].onclick = function() {
      alert(i);
   }
}
Который для правильной работы переписали
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
   (function(i) {
      links[i].onclick = function() {
         alert(i);
      }
   })(i);
}.

Comment: Я понял, что вы хотите сделать. Если честно, мне лень еще раз переписывать мой пост выше. Возьмите бумажку и построчно напишите, что делает ваш код после нажатия на кнопку.

Нормально это выглядит так: http://jsfiddle.net/2z5rhvLL/2/